# Using a configuration class in an external module

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an angular application that uses some external modules.

My final application contains some configuration classes that hold for example values of URLs, messages keys that are exchanged with the server,...etc

As an example, let's say that the following class is defined in my final application:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class Messages {
    private static _instance: Messages;

    public static readonly ERROR_HTTP_INTERNAL: string = "error.http.internal";
    public static readonly ERROR_HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED: string = "error.http.unauthorized";
    public static readonly ERROR_HTTP_FORBIDDEN: string = "error.http.forbidden";

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

I want to use this class in an external module in order to display error messages if ever an http error occurs:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // Do stuff with response
      }
    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      if (errorResponse instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        let errorKey: string = errorResponse.error;
        if (!errorKey) {
          switch (errorResponse.status) {
            case 401:
              errorKey = Messages.ERROR_HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
              break;
            case 403:
              errorKey = Messages.ERROR_HTTP_FORBIDDEN;
              break;
            default:
              errorKey = Messages.ERROR_HTTP_INTERNAL;
              break;
          }

          //Manage the display of the error message
        }

        //Manage the display of the error message
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1. How to export the `Messages` class of my final application to the `HttpErrorInterceptor` class of my external module?
2. Is this modules separation a good approach? Would it not be better if the `HttpErrorInterceptor` remain in the final application or define it in a more simple way in the external module?

Answer (score 0):

You could **store your messages in a json file** and read it when the application starts using a **MessageService**. Then you can inject this service wherever you need it:

Your MessageService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

  public messages: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  loadMessages(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('./../../../assets/messages.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then((data: any) => {
        this.config = data;
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        Promise.resolve();
      });
  }
}
```

Your app.module.ts:

```
import { MessageService } from './services/messages/message.service';

export function messageServiceFactory(messageService: MessageService): Function {
  return () => messageService.loadMessages();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  // ...
  ]

providers: [

    MessageService,
    {
      // Provider for APP_INITIALIZER
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: messageServiceFactory,
      deps: [MessageService],
      multi: true,
    },
    //...

    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And use it like this somwhere else:

```
@Injectable()
export class AnotherService {
constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

doStuff() {
    console.log('ERROR_HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED', 
    this.messageService.messages.ERROR_HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How could the `MessageService` be recognizable in an external module project?

Comment: It's the final application that includes the external module, so how can a class defined in the final application be accessible in a module or project that it uses?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean with "external". I only know Angular modules. Then again, I am no expert :)

Comment: It's in fact a separate project module that defined outside my final application, and it's then imported as any other npm project

Comment: I don't think you could share Services like that accross projects.

Comment: It's my thought too, I think that I must change the approach of the way I defined my service in the external module, and implement it more adequately